# multiple call body multicoreprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using the module multiprocessing in python. Before I call my main function with the mapping function, I need to get some input from the user. My problem is that the code before the main function gets executed multiple times when I call the main function with pool.map
This very simple code illustrates my problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
result=range(1,5)
print('start')
def test(a):
    print(a+10)
if __name__=="__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(test,result)
```

my output then reads:

```
start
start
11
12
13
14
start
```

Why does the code before the test function execute multiple times?

Comment: It doesn't (using Python 3.5 here). The order of the number in the output varies, so everything works as expected.

Comment: but start is still printed three times no matter the order it is printed in. Does that not mean that the print statement and thus the code before the test function is executed three times when it should only run once?
This problem extends to when I try to get some input from the user the input also is asked multiple times

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output - it will only print "start"

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: I am using PyCharm and Python version 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not display "start" for me with python 3.4.

Don't know your version of Python, but it might be because in each process of the pool, your file is imported and then the test function is executed. It means that code written "globally", is executed once at start of the process.

I have to admit it is weird as it means the sub processes are not forked but launch/import the current python script themselves.

Anyway, to respect PEP8, you should do it more this way :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test(a):
    print(a+10)

def main():
    result=range(1,5)
    print('start')
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(test,result)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: perfect this works for me thanks!
so that means that whenever I want to run a script which includes pool.map I have to put all the code that I only want to be executed once into its own function right?

Comment: Yes indeed. And in general, no code should be written at the "base" of the file, only imports, function/class definitions, and a tail like --- if \_\_name\_\_=="\_\_main\_\_" --- if the file is to be executed.